# How can i use a variable from another ambit into a child Widget?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Hello I have a problem when I want to use the List variable that stores the IDs of a database in Firebase. I would like to use it in the "Row" widget where I create a DropDownButton, it only allows me to do it if the instance is out of scope. How can i use this variable inside Row?

**Main.dart**

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Material App',
        // home: const CardScreen(),
        initialRoute: AppRoutes.initialRoute,
        routes: AppRoutes.routes,
        onGenerateRoute: AppRoutes.onGenerateRoute);
  }
}
```

**Form1_screen.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class FormularioScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const FormularioScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FormularioScreen> createState() => _FormularioScreenState();
}

class _FormularioScreenState extends State<FormularioScreen> {
  _FormularioScreenState();

  // ignore: prefer_typing_uninitialized_variables
  var selecCurrency;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(
          'PET-SOS PERRO',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
        ),
        iconTheme: const IconThemeData(
          color: Colors.black, //change your color here
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          StreamBuilder(
            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Razas').snapshots(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return const Text('Loading');
              } else {
                List<DropdownMenuItem> currencyItems = [];
                for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.data.docs.length; i++) {
                  DocumentSnapshot snap = snapshot.data.docs[i];
                  currencyItems.add(
                    DropdownMenuItem(
                      child: Text(
                        snap.id,
                      ),
                      value: snap.id,
                    ),
                  );
                }
              }
              return Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  DropdownButton<dynamic>(
                      items: currencyItems,
                      onChanged: (currencyValue) {
                        var snackBar = SnackBar(
                            content: Text('Se seleccionó $currencyValue'));
                        // ignore: deprecated_member_use
                        Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
                        setState(() {
                          selecCurrency = currencyValue;
                        });
                      },
                      value: selecCurrency,
                      hint: const Text('Seleccione una raza.')),
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
          StreamBuilder(
            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Peso').snapshots(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return const Text('Loading');
              } else {
                List<DropdownMenuItem> currencyItems = [];
                for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.data.docs.length; i++) {
                  DocumentSnapshot snap = snapshot.data.docs[i];
                  currencyItems.add(
                    DropdownMenuItem(
                      child: Text(
                        snap.id,
                      ),
                      value: snap.id,
                    ),
                  );
                }
              }
              return Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  DropdownButton<dynamic>(
                      items: currencyItems,
                      onChanged: (currencyValue) {
                        var snackBar = SnackBar(
                            content: Text('Se seleccionó $currencyValue'));
                        // ignore: deprecated_member_use
                        Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
                        setState(() {
                          selecCurrency = currencyValue;
                        });
                      },
                      value: selecCurrency,
                      hint: const Text('Seleccione un peso.')),
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
          StreamBuilder(
            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Edad').snapshots(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return const Text('Loading');
              } else {
                List<DropdownMenuItem> currencyItems = [];
                for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.data.docs.length; i++) {
                  DocumentSnapshot snap = snapshot.data.docs[i];
                  currencyItems.add(
                    DropdownMenuItem(
                      child: Text(
                        snap.id,
                      ),
                      value: snap.id,
                    ),
                  );
                }
              }
              return Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  DropdownButton<dynamic>(
                      items: currencyItems,
                      onChanged: (currencyValue) {
                        var snackBar = SnackBar(
                            content: Text('Se seleccionó $currencyValue'));
                        // ignore: deprecated_member_use
                        Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
                        setState(() {
                          selecCurrency = currencyValue;
                        });
                      },
                      value: selecCurrency,
                      hint: const Text('Seleccione una edad.')),
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Basically the variable isn't define because it's outsite of the ambit.**

[image]

Comment: what error does it throw?

Comment: Hi @Delwinn the error sounds like this: Undefined name 'currencyItems'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.

Comment: is currencyItems a list? if so, items take int value. use `currencyItems.length`

Comment: @Delwinn currencyitems is a "List<DropdownMenuItem> currencyItems = [];".

Comment: change `item:currencyItems` to `item: currencyItems.length`

Comment: @Delwinn same issue, the varible isn't define.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245334/discussion-between-delwinn-and-clemente-aravena).

Comment: move the list definition before the scaffold
List<DropdownMenuItem> currencyItems = [];
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

Answer (score 0):

move the list definition before the scaffold

```
class _FormularioScreenState extends State<FormularioScreen> {
_FormularioScreenState();

// ignore: prefer_typing_uninitialized_variables
var selecCurrency;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  List<DropdownMenuItem> currencyItems = []; // <= ADD
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: const Text(
        'PET-SOS PERRO',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
      ),
      iconTheme: const IconThemeData(
        color: Colors.black, //change your color here
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    ),
    body: Column(
      children: [
        StreamBuilder(
          stream: 
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Razas').snapshots(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return const Text('Loading');
            } else {
              List<DropdownMenuItem> currencyItems = []; // <= REMOVE
              for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.data.docs.length; i++) {
```